# '' Think'' and '' Find'' in a comparative sentence

Tags: word-usage, comparative

I know that the structure '' Find something/ someone + Adj'' can be rewritten using '' Think someone/ something + to be + Adj''.

- I find this book interesting= I think this book is interesting.

However, when it comes to comparative structures, I wonder if we can use '' find'' in place of '' think''?
For example: I think tigers are more beautiful than cheetahs. => I find tigers more beautiful than cheetahs.
I think it works, but am not so sure. Please help me to clear up this doubt! Thank you : )

Answer (score 0):

This is accurate, but it is important to clarify that "I find this very interesting" implies "In my personal opinion, this is very interesting", but in a sentence like "I think this one is better", if you emphasize "I", you can change the sentence to "I find this one is better", but if you emphasize "think", meaning you are uncertain, then you cannot substitute "find" for "think".